# Why is the evaluation order in python always from left to right？

Tags: python

> Python evaluates expressions from left to right. Notice that while evaluating an assignment, the right-hand side is evaluated before the left-hand side.
>
> In the following lines, expressions will be evaluated in the arithmetic order of their suffixes:

> expr1 + expr2 * (expr3 - expr4)

why is the expr1 evaluated before expr3? In my opinion,(expr3 - expr4) is calculated before +

Comment: It is true that `(expr3 - expr4)` will be computed before the multiplication and addition, but that is unrelated to how the individual parts are evaluated.  What it's saying is that, if `expr1` happens to be a function call, that function will be called before `expr3` and `expr4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it a bit clearer, consider this example:

```py
def expr1():
    return 1

def expr2():
    return 2

def expr3():
    return 3

def expr4():
    return 4

expr1() + expr2() * (expr3() - expr4())
```

The order of operations will be:

1. `tmp1 = expr1()`
2. `tmp2 = expr2()`
3. `tmp3 = expr3()`
4. `tmp4 = expr4()`
5. `tmp5 = tmp3 - tmp4`
6. `tmp6 = tmp2 * tmp5`
7. `result = tmp1 + tmp6`

### Counterexample

If we instead write

```py
(expr1() + expr2()) * expr3() - expr4()
```

we get

1. `tmp1 = expr1()`
2. `tmp2 = expr2()`
3. `tmp3 = tmp1 + tmp2`
4. `tmp4 = expr3()`
5. `tmp5 = tmp3 * tmp4`
6. `tmp6 = expr4()`
7. `result = tmp5 - tmp6`

The point that they are trying to make in the quoted text is that evaluation *starts* on the left. If you write `expr1() + expr2()`, the interpreter could evaluate either sub-expression first. It will choose `expr1()` first.

### Why is this important?

Expressions may have side-effects where the order of operations matter, e.g. by manipulating a global variable. Additionally, not all operations are associative. For example for floating point math, it matters whether `a + b + c` is evaluated as `(a + b) + c` or `a + (b + c)`

### Why is left-to-right not obvious?

Other languages use other orders, for example OCaml is right-to-left. Also, compiled languages give some liberty in order to optimize the evaluation. For example in C/C++, `expr1(expr2(), expr3())` does not define whether `expr2` or `expr3` is evaluated first.